# Parsing a book into chapters – Python

Tags: python, regex, parsing, text-analysis

I have a large book stored in a single plain text file and want to parse it in order to create individual files for each chapter. I some simple regex that finds each chapter title, but I'm struggling at capturing all of the text in between.

```
import re

txt = open('book.txt', 'r')

for line in txt :
    if re.match("^[A-Z]+$", line):
        print line,
```

I know this is fairly rudimentary, but I'm new enough to python that it's got me a bit stumped. At the moment I'm going line by line, so my thought process is:

1. If the line is a chapter title: Make a new file 'chapter_title.txt'
2. If the next line isn't a chapter title: Write the line to chapter_title.txt

My attempts to actually write that out have been less successful though. Appreciate the help!

**Edit:** Specifically, I'm confused by the Python syntax for file I/O. I've tried:

```
for line in txt :
    if re.match("^[A-Z]+$", line):
        f = open(line + '.txt', 'w')
    else f.write(line + "\n")
```

as my general approach, but that's not gonna work as written. Hoping for help structuring the loops. Thanks

Comment: What exactly is the question? Looks like you're in the right direction.

Comment: Basically I'm looking for help with the syntax. The structure makes sense to me but I'm struggling with the file I/O

Comment: @gweintraub Hmm...How do you know if the line is a chapter or not?

Comment: can you post some text from input file?

Comment: @KevinGuan My regex finds the chapter titles. They're formatted in all caps and are on a line by themselves. That part of the code works for sure.

Comment: @hackaholic I'm actually using A Game of Thrones as my corpus. It's formatted:

ARYA
[a few thousand words of text] \n \n \n \n \n TYRION etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work:

```
import re

with open('book.txt', 'r') as file:
    txt = file.readlines()

f = False

for line in txt:
    if re.match("^[A-Z]+$", line):
        if f: f.close()
        f = open(line + '.txt', 'w')

    else:
        f.write(line + "\n")
```

---

Maybe I should add some explanation:

1. `with` will auto close the file. Close an opened file is important.
2. `readlines()` function can read the file by lines and save the output to a list.
3. Here I'm using `f = False`. So first time `if f:` will be `False`.

Now here is important, if the file `f` has been opened, then `if f:` will be `True` and the file will be closed by `f.close()`(but the first time `f.close()` will not run).

And then, `f = open(line + '.txt', 'w')` will write text into that file, when `re.match("^[A-Z]+$", line)` is `True` the file will be closed, and open another file, and again, again until the `txt` list is empty.

Comment: @gweintraub I've just added some explanation. Maybe you'd like see them :)

Comment: I'm getting `AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'write' ` and I think it makes sense.. is it a bug? (bug caused by the last line of course..)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can also try the following:

```
import re

with open('book.txt', 'r') as file:
    lines = file.read()

contents = re.split("[A-Z]+", lines)
for i in range(1, len(contents), 2):
    with open(contents[i] + '.txt', 'w') as file:
        file.write(contents[i+1])
```

The book contents are split by the chapter title. The resulting chapter contents (`contents[i+1]`) are then written in the chapter file (`contents[i] + '.txt'`).

Edit: this assumes that you have a fixed pattern for the chapter titles.

Answer (score -1):

## You asked for help with syntax.

The full grammar of python is here https://docs.python.org/2/reference/grammar.html?highlight=grammar.

Check out more wordy python docs here @ https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-if-statement to read up on compound statements (with, for & if) to know the syntax more accurately.

Also, see https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open for knowing about the Built-In function open().

Stay consistent with the indentation of code blocks and remember that a `:`
must follow every statement before the suite.

```
import re

with open('book.txt', 'r') as corpus:
    eye = corpus.readlines()

verdad = False
lambda l: re.match("^[A-Z]+$", l)

for line in eye:
    if l(line):
        if verdad: verdad.close()
        verdad = open(line.replace(' ','_') + '.txt', 'w')
    elif ! l(line):
        if verdad: verdad.close()
    else:
        verdad.write(line + "\n")
```